# Can NSDateFormatter format a date relative to a time other than the current time?

Tags: cocoa, nsdateformatter

When using `NSDateFormatter` with `doesRelativeDateFormatting` turned on, all relative formatting seems to be relative to the current system time. I would like to format dates with relative formatting, such as "Today" or "Tomorrow", but relative to an arbitrary "current" time instead of the actual time.

For example, I would like to specify an `NSDate` of November 2, 2015, with November 1, 2015 as the "current" time, and have it formatted as "Tomorrow" instead of "November 2, 2015". Can `NSDateFormatter` do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is always relative to the system date. sorry.

BUT

there is https://github.com/billgarrison/SORelativeDateTransformer that might be able to do this. maybe you can get code from there

Comment: That link didn't really work for my needs, so I wound up writing my own thing. The answer is definitely no though.